# Why AWS Lambda function in Java returns blank JSON

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am not getting why my AWS Lambda function returns {} i.e. blank JSON even if there is a response getting print CloudWatch log.

Here is my code. Fetching details from S3. And in logs, I can see those details in log. But when I test lambda function, I get {} and not the actual response. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

One more thing I noticed here. When I change return type to String instead of JSONObject, I get expected JSON string. Strange. Isn't it?

```
    public class GetItemDetailsHandler implements RequestHandler<Object, JSONObject>{

    static AmazonS3 s3Client;

    static {
        s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY));
    }

    public JSONObject handleRequest(Object obj, Context context) {

        String key = "somePath";

        S3Object s3object = s3Client.getObject(BUCKET_NAME, key);
        context.getLogger().log("s3object content = "+ s3object.getObjectContent());
        context.getLogger().log("s3object metatdata = "+ s3object.getObjectMetadata());

        JSONObject itemDetails = null;
        try {
            itemDetails = getJSONObjectFromS3Object(s3object.getObjectContent(), context);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            context.getLogger().log("Exception while parsing JSON. Exception =>" + e.getMessage());
        }
        context.getLogger().log("itemDetails = "+ itemDetails);
        context.getLogger().log("itemDetails class = "+ itemDetails.getClass());

        return itemDetails;
    }

     private static JSONObject getJSONObjectFromS3Object(InputStream is, Context context) throws IOException {
        if (is == null)
            return null;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, StringUtils.UTF8));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }

        context.getLogger().log("JSON = "+ sb.toString());
        return new JSONObject(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you consuming this? May we see the client code?

Comment: I am getting { }. Unless I get some value, how will I consume!!

Comment: Where are you seeing {}? Is this in AWS console (or) do you have another client program? if AWS console tester, then can you please post the Test code too? What is the value you are seeing for console.log statement  context.getLogger().log("itemDetails = "+ itemDetails);

Comment: When you define a Lambda function in AWS, there is a "Test" button available  to test your function. Just provide JSON input and it executes your function against that input and provide result. That statement prints actual son like {"name": "abc", "details":"xyzzy"}

Comment: I know, I want to make sure that is what you are doing.

Comment: I think why JSONObject is not working might be due to the fact that supported Input/Output Types (Java) which are described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model-req-resp.html. I am not 100% sure whether JSONObject is POJO or not. Another simple test you could do might be create a test POJO in your package and return that instead of JSONObject (just to prove our assumption). Something like described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-using-predefined-interfaces.html

Comment: @NGR I have the same problem, how did you resolve this?